# VLAN can reach all other VLANs but nothing can reach it

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, hp-procurve

I'm using Meraki and I've created a VLAN (111) that broadcasts over its own SSID wirelessly. I've added the VLAN ID (111) to the HP hardware switches involved and added all ports as tagged to the VLAN in the configuration.

I can get internet and intranet access while associated on the new VLAN (111) but nothing can ping the devices on the 111 VLAN. I have not set up any additional firewall rules.

Is there some additional hardware switch mapping i have to do to allow 2 way communication? Or where do i even start?

Procurve config:
[image]

SSID config:
[image]

VLAN config:
[image]

Comment: You need to edit your question with more details. Start with the router and firewall configurations, and a diagram of the network would be a good thing, too.

Comment: You need to clarify your configuration on the switches involved and other devices with your vlan 111, network diagram can help too.

Comment: One moment. I don't have a network diagram, but there is nothing fancy going on. Just a Meraki router going to a Procurve switch that extends out to some wireless APs. What exactly would i need to show you with the configuration? Thanks

Comment: One thing i can say is that i tried adding firewall rules initially and they were registering allowed/denials but the ping never reached the destination. So it makes me think it's getting hung up in the switch, after the router, on its way back to the destination. Either the switch or the access point.

Comment: Can you not  ping any vlan 111 device from your router??

Comment: @OrlandoGaetano The router can ping the device it looks like.

Comment: By your configuration, traffic that goes from your switch to your AP are tagged??,

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I've just marked all ports on the switch as tagged for VLAN 111  to eliminate confusion for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the problem was that the device i had connected to the network over wifi had the network type set to "public", which didn't allow other computers on the network to reach it. Sorry for confusing everyone.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting what the problem was (even though it turned out to be something silly, happens to all of us from time to time).. Please mark your answer as accepted so this doesn't get treated as an unasnwered question.

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off base as I haven't touched a Procurve in a long time but I think because you have trunk ports configured on the Meraki that you need to trunk on the Procurve side as well and tag for the VLANs you want to pass. See this link for possibilities: https://documentation.meraki.com/MS/Port_and_VLAN_Configuration/Recommended_Configuration_for_Trunk_Link_to_Non-Meraki_Switches

Comment: HP Procurves don't have a "trunk" port mode, you can have 1 untagged and a multitude of tagged VLANs assigned to a specific port. To accept VLAN tagged traffic with a specific VLANID, the port has to have that VLAN assigned as "tagged". It's a bit weird if you're used to Cisco, but has it's advantages sometime. There's also dynamic VLAN ports, but that's another can of worms.